# Faster Copying of Data in Arrays to Destinations, While Applying a Scaling or Offset Factor

Tags: c++, arrays, math, memory, double

I have a structure with arrays that often need to be copied and can be quite large.

```
struct XYZ
{
   ...
   double *x, *y, *z;
   uint count;
};
```

Now Daniel Vik in his blog...
http://www.danielvik.com/2010/02/fast-memcpy-in-c.html
...presents this code as a faster means to copy contiguous arrays in c++ (it's faster because it lacks the error check of memcpy and some of the special conditions stuff):

```
void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t count) {
    char* dst8 = (char*)dest;
    char* src8 = (char*)src;
    --src8;
    --dst8;

    while (count--) {
        *++dst8 = *++src8;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

I've tweaked this somewhat, as I know my types and typically `count--` is more expensive than `--count` as it returns a new copy.  So my result is:

```
struct XYZ
{
   void Copy(XYZ & dest) 
   {
        size_t len = count * sizeof(double)+1;
        char* dest8_x = (char*)dest.x;
        char* dest8_y = (char*)dest.y;
        char* dest8_z = (char*)dest.z;
        char* src8_x = (char*)x;
        char* src8_y = (char*)y;
        char* src8_z = (char*)z;
        --dest8_x;
        --dest8_y;
        --dest8_z;
        --src_x;
        --src_y;
        --src_z;
        while (--len)
        {
            *++dest8_x = *++src8_x;
            *++dest8_y = *++src8_y;
            *++dest8_z = *++src8_z;
        }
    }

   ...
   double *x, *y, *z;
   uint count;
};
```

Now I have a couple questions about making the most out of this strategy:

1. If I copy to 2 targets... say `XYZ & dest1` and `XYZ & dest2` the same memory from `*this` will it be more efficient to interleave them or copy all the members of one structure then the next?
2. If I want to apply some scaling factor `double coefficientA` or `double offsetB` either via addition or multiplication to one value or a range of values, is it possible to incorporate this more efficiently into my copy operation.

To offer a brief justification for the desire to optimize, sometimes `count>100000` for a given run of my program, and often the first thing I do to a copied set of coordinates is add a chosen value consistently to all of them.

Comment: If you care that much about performance, benchmark it. My educated guess is, three straightforward `memcpy` calls will be faster than all this fancy footwork.

Comment: Are you sure? I've seen multiple posts on stack overflow saying `memcpy` implements multiple conditionals... boundary checks etc. that make it slower than bare bones assemble/pointer based implementations.. tbh I'm not sure what these are, but they came from highly rated commenters.

Comment: If I were sure, I wouldn't say "guess". If you want to be sure, implement it and measure it.

Comment: Sure, that's trivial for the interleaving question, just wondering if there was a general trend in a case like this to be aware of.  As for the scaling/adding of an offset, it's more a matter of not knowing how to do that in an optimized way.

Comment: Intel itself says memcpy in gcc is not optimized... I'm primarily targeting my code for Linux users.  See....
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memcpy-performance

...straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: That article is from 2009. I would be surprised if no progress was made in the past four years (but I don't myself use GCC and don't have any particular insight). In any case, even if GCC's implementation is not perfect, what makes you believe that **yours** is? The article talks about SSE instructions and stuff; you certainly don't use any of that.

Comment: If you insist on your own implementation, wouldn't `for(char* end = src8 + count; src8 != end; *++dst8 = *++src8);` save you one addition per iteration?

Comment: also compare with `std::copy`.  However I susoect max performance for large blocks may require assembly and copying more than a byte at a time?

Comment: Thanks Yakk, that's a good suggestion.

Comment: @Igor.... As I said the basic idea I implemented wasn't mine... it was suggested on a code optimization blog (by Daniel Vik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be a comment, though it seems too large.

First, why copy 1 byte at a time, when you could be doing 16!? Next, I notice your use of both scaling and offset - two common operations in3d/2d graphics. I wonder if the approach used there wouldn't be more appropriate - I.e store the coordinates and a separate transformation matrix. This may eliminate entirely the need to copy the coords. You may need to take into account the cache. Moving large amounts of data around can thrash it. Also, assuming you need to do something else with the doubles each cycle you could find that loading them into fpu registers, transforming then using them (every frame/cycle) to be quicker than loading, changing, saving to a new spot(uncertain repetition rate) followed by loading and using them (every frame/cycle) - I can't help but think it sounds like well intentioned but premature optimization.

To be honest, I think it isn't possible to give you a definitive answer with regards to optimizing your particular program without a much greater idea of it particulars. But in any case, copying structs of 3 doubles, a byte at a time ain't gonna be it!

Comment: You're correct, the program uses 3D coordinates, however it only applies one transformation per cycle and further it only uses two operations -- a rotation of a set of points (consecutive in the array) about a given point and a translation of a set of points... I use:
http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

for rotation... The only thing I don't have is an explicit matrix class (as I see no real performance advantage in that).... instead I do the appropriate ops on the individal vars for each index in the series.

Comment: Ah-hah! Well, since it is about 3d graphics and will have transformations applied continuously, I would further advise you to use a matrix of some sort - whether it be wrapped-up in a tidy class or as simple as a `double matrix[16];` By continuously changing the points actual co-ordinates, rather than continuously recalculating the numbers needed to transform them, you will encounter cumulative error. By recalculating the matrix each frame, you consistently have '1* a small error' added to each coordinate. Otherwise, you have 'frameNum * a small error' added to each.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, that's what I'm currently doing sans the matrix class... each frame I recalculate the sin/cos for three random angles, then loop through my series of points shifting each point to the origin, applying the rotation to each axis and then shifting it back...

Comment: @JasonR.Mick - Sounds good. I've done the same thing myself eons ago. Using openGL now, rather than home-brew polyfill, clipping, blah-blah routines - I find the matrix approach more natural. As for performance - I guess when you think about it, - one involves: load, transform, store, load, use per frame. The other involves: load, transform, use per frame. I suspect the transformation matrix approach to be better  on the cache than the approach that involves copying the co-ordinates to different places in memory, too - hence more speed, more or less for free.